# Change base.Visibility after animation complete in Visibility property

Tags: c#, animation

I've made an slide animation in `C#` that triggers when the `Visibility` of the UserControl changes. I've done this by replacing the current `Visibility` property with an new one like this.

```
public new Visibility Visibility
```

And to update the Visibility in the base class is use `base.Visibility` and fill it the `value` field of `set` in the property, like this.

```
base.Visibility = value;
```

I've also added my `Storyboard` in `set`, with an `if` check to see if value is Visible of Hidden.

When i open my UserControl the Visibility is updated before the animation is played, this goes without problems.

When i close my UserControl the Visiblity is suppose to updated after the animation is completed, but the new `Visibility` value is not set in `base.Visibility`.

I've tried to do this in Xaml using `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` as shown shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317875/wpf-fade-out-on-a-control) post to set the visibility, but this was to slow to update the button image i use to open the UserControl.

This is the code i have so fare.

```
public new Visibility Visibility
{
    get { return base.Visibility; }
    set
    {
        double marginNumber = Width * -1;
        Storyboard board = null;

        try
        {
            board = (Storyboard)FindResource("Slide");
            Storyboard.SetTarget(board, this);
        }
        catch (Exception) { }

        if (value == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
        {    
            Margin = new Thickness(Margin.Left, Margin.Top, marginNumber, Margin.Bottom);
            base.Visibility = value;
            if (board != null)
            {
                ((ThicknessAnimation)board.Children[0]).To = new Thickness(Margin.Left, Margin.Top, 0, Margin.Bottom);
                ((ThicknessAnimation)board.Children[0]).From = Margin;
                board.Begin();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (board != null)
            {
                ((ThicknessAnimation)board.Children[0]).To = new Thickness(Margin.Left, Margin.Top, marginNumber, Margin.Bottom);
                ((ThicknessAnimation)board.Children[0]).From = Margin;
                EventHandler handle = null;
                handle += (s, e) =>
                {
                    board.Stop();
                    board.Completed -= handle;

                    base.Visibility = value; <<-- This one does not update.
                };
                board.Completed += handle;
                board.Begin();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why is my visibility not set when the animation event is compleet? Or should i use the method in the post that i linked?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why the Visibility is unchanged, but hiding the Visibility property is a very bad idea. Why not name it CustomVisibility, so you know what you are calling? Also, having a property setter perform such complex logic is just asking for trouble. And did you try to debug? Is the completed Handler really called?