# Fading out a WPF control on Visibility.Hidden

Tags: c#, wpf, visibility, fadeout

I'd like to use style to make a WPF control (in this case a 3rd party one from Telerik, but could be anything) fade out as it's Visibility property is changed to Hidden. This approach I'm trying to use works well for fading *in* content after it's set to Visibility.Visible. But this does NOT work the opposite way:

```
<Style x:Key="FadeoutStyle" TargetType="telerik:RadDiagramShape">
    <Style.Triggers>              
        <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                 From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>               
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I'm pretty sure of why this doesn't work: as soon as the control is set to Hidden, WPF stops drawing it. So my animation might even be playing, but it's not showing because Visibility.Hidden immediately got applied.

Question 1: Is my assumption correct? Question 2: What is a good pattern to work around this? I can imagine a solution where a custom property initiates the fadeout anim and uses a callback once done that applies the actual Visibility.Hidden setting. Is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4318320/1136211

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Fade Out on a control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317875/wpf-fade-out-on-a-control)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visibility.Hidden issues aside, ultimately it turned out that I was using the trigger incorrectly. My working version (using a different property) looks like this:

```
  <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
      <Trigger.EnterActions>
          <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
              </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
      </Trigger.EnterActions>
      <Trigger.ExitActions>
          <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard>
                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
              </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
      </Trigger.ExitActions>
  </Trigger>
```